# Porous object, texture or geometry?

Tags: modeling, materials, particles

I'm trying to model something like this (sorry for the small picture)

[image: porous microparticle]

that is basically a half sphere made of sintered or aggregated smaller spheres, like a thick multilayer.  I was wondering if this could be achieved by simulating gravity with lots of smaller particles and them emptying the core, or with a particle system of any kind, or even with a solidified sphere with a porous texture, any idea?  I'm not that knowledgeable in Blender.

Comment: if you have a close-up picture you could use it as a bump map, or as you say, particles, but actually your picture is very low quality so it's hard to say

Comment: Particles are very computationally expensive and likely overkill, unless you are going to do some serious closeups. Otherwise you could probably do away with displacement, micro-displacement, bump mapping, or even a good diffuse texture might suffice

Comment: I actually need a closeup, I will try with a particle system (few thousand only) and if not, micro-displacement.  Thanks for the insights.

Comment: and don't forget that with particles or displacement you can bake to make it much lighter  ;)

Comment: For porous objects like that, maybe the tissue add-on would work.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gM8yEMFMjg, where the author is using a sphere as a volume container, and then sets up a particle system emitting from the volume.  I haven't managed to run the physics simulation to avoid particle overlapping, but in my case should be good enough.

[image: final render]